# Creating a counter inside a Python for loop

Tags: python, loops

Obviously, if we do this, the counter will remain at 0 as it is reset at the start of every iteration:

```
for thing in stuff:
    count = 0
    print count
    count =+1
    write_f.write(thing)
```

But as I have this code inside of function, it does not work to do this either:

```
count=0
for thing in stuff:
    print count
    count =+1
    write_f.write(thing)
```

I have several different indent levels, and no matter how I move `count=0`about, it either is without effect or throws `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`. Is there a way to produce a simple interation counter just inside the for loop itself?

Comment: `count =+1` -> `count += 1`

Comment: Not true. Your second code works fine (apart from the typo Johnny points out). You need to show the actual code and error.

Comment: You could also use `enumerate`.  `for count, thing in enumerate(stuff):`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This (creating an extra variable before the for-loop) is *not* pythonic .

The pythonic way to iterate over items while having an extra counter is using `enumerate`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(iterable):
    print(index, item)
```

So, for example for a list `lst` this would be:

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c"]

for index, item in enumerate(lst):
  print(index, item)
```

...and generate the output:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

---

You are strongly recommended to always use Python's [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html) for creating "pythonic solutions" whenever possible. There is also the documentation for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate).

---

If you need more information on enumerate, you can look up [PEP 279 -- The enumerate() built-in function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/).

Comment: This is the same information as the linked duplicate. It should've just been closed as a duplicate.